# Regex designing for special string

Tags: java, regex

Unable to implement regex for string in line starts with `?` and ends with `;`
appended with single quotes or double quotes.

for example:

```
?abcdef;
'?abcdef;'
"?abcdef;"
```

I tried a lot, like this `"^\\?([^;]+)\\;$"` but it did not work.

Test code snippet:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String text = "This is param-start ?abcdef; param-end";

        final String patternString = "(['\"]?)\\?.*;\\1";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        System.out.println("lookingAt = " + matcher.lookingAt());
        System.out.println("matches   = " + matcher.matches());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `^(['"]?)\?.*;\1$` will do? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/psUs84/2). Java: `s.matches("(['\"]?)\\?.*;\\1")`.

Comment: Please add a code snippet showing how you test the regex to the question.

Comment: added code snippet @Wiktor

Comment: You seem to need a partial match, so use it with `.find()`, `while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("matches   = " + matcher.group());
     }`, and the regex should be `String patternString = "(['\"]?)\\?.*?;\\1"`. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/OKe9kW).

Comment: What do you expect to get? If your string has line breaks, use the `"(?s)(['\"]?)\\?.*?;\\1"` regex, but it is not clear what you call "not working" and how to make it "working" for you.

Comment: it is working Wiktor Thanks a lot, I am trying one more regex will take a help from u if not able to design thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
final String text = "This is param-start ?abcdef; param-end";
final String patternString = "(['\"]?)\\?.*?;\\1";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found: " + matcher.group());
}
// => Match found: = ?abcdef;
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OKe9kW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UE2LKU/2).  Regulex graph:

[image]

**Notes**:

- `while (matcher.find())` - iterates through all potential matches in the string
- `matcher.group()` - accesses the match value.

**Regex**

- `(['"]?)` - Capturing group 1: either `'` or `"`
- `\?` - a `?` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible (the pattern is compiled with `Pattern.DOTALL`, so it will match across line breaks, too)
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\1` - the same value as captured in Group 1.

Comment: `"matches   = "` is a bit confusing

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex:

```
(["']?)\?.*;\1
```

For Java use:

```
final String pattern = "(['\"]?)\\?.*;\\1";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/51PnTL/1)

- `(["']?)` matches an **optional** `'` or `"` and captures in group #1
- `\1` is back-reference for the same value as in group #1

Comment: You need to call `matcher.find()`

Comment: This works great +1. @Girish [Check this demo](https://rextester.com/MWO62634) Prints `true`

Answer (score 0):

Your description stated "starts with ? and ends with ;", but your sample string does not end with a semicolon - it's ending with wtih a double quote.

If you want to allow the string to start or end with either a single quote or double quote, your match should be:
`^['"]?\?[^;]+;\['"]?$`